# Quantify Branch-specific changes in Bazaar

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I've been working on a fork of critical component of our source tree, and I'm interested to see how many changes have been made. I originally `bzr branch`'d the project, but because of paralell development I have been doing a `bzr merge` to stay up-to-date.

How can I see only the changes I've been commiting in this branch?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [bzr documentation](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.2/en/user-reference/revisionspec-help.html) `submit:` revision identifier can be used to see only your changes, so running in your branch

```
bzr diff -r submit:
```

should show you your changes without merged changes.

You can also inspect the diff of your changes how they will look after merge to the trunk, run

```
bzr merge --preview YOUR_BRANCH
```

in the main branch (trunk).

Answer (score 1):

from command line:
bzr log --forward > somefile.txt

View the file, any commit that is not labeled [merge] happened on that branch.  I hope this answers your question.  Perhaps I'm reading it wrong.  BTW the --forward bit will cause the history to be placed in somefile.txt in forward chrono order rather than the default revers chrono.